# discord.js - bot timing out

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I recently created a discord.js bot with node.js. However, I can't start my bot, because its timing out.

```
Error: Something took too long to do.
at timeout.client.setTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\tntbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\ClientManager.js:40:57)
at Timeout.setTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\tntbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:422:7)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

That's what I get on every start.
I checked the code, it has no problem.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you have a connection problem. May be a proxy blocking it. Can you add a small `hello world`-ish code that reproduce the bug ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, and I found the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

For some strange reasons, Discord generated a new token, and I used the old one.

Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Have a great day!

Comment: Accept your own answer please!

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be making a new project and redoing the `npm install discord.js` because it looks like there's a problem in the `node_modules` as it didn't download correctly.
One more thing to avoid errors that appear every now and then, add this line in your code after declaring the client/bot variable:

`client.on('error' => console.log);`
   or
   `bot.on('error' => console.log);`

This will log the error with its details to the console without actually terminating node.js.
I hope I understood your question correctly, btw... this is my first answer to a user here :D